# Emberjs - Which file do I insert my Handlebars.registerHelper into

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, helper

Which file do I insert my Handlebars.registerHelper into?

Example. At the bottom of my object's controller/view/model/etc.

The ember docs (http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/) say to insert it into my Javascript, but being that 90% of my project is javascript, it doesn't narrow my search.

Here's the helpers i want to insert into  my object called 'Doc'

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toss it in *any* javascript file included after Handlebars and EmberJS has been inserted, you can just create any random js file and include it after Handlebars and EmberJS in the page.  That is an invalid helper for two reasons though.

1. You register helpers using `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper(...)` or `Ember.Handlebars.helpers`  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_simple-example
2. helpers with blocks won't work (it will look like it works the first time, but when one of the values changes you'll get an error) http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_use-with-blocks-not-supported

Comment: So tossing valid helpers into a DocView will yield the same results as popping it in after the DocModel or DocController?

Comment: Exactly.  Are you using some sort of build product like ember-cli/ember-app-kit.

Comment: I think I'm using ember-app-kit as it is mentioned as <file path="$PROJECT_DIR$/../ember-app-kit/package.json" changelist="71f0a48c-3bc0-482b-b2b0-9f60ab17e680" time="1376926689682" ignored="false" /> in grunt-ember-templates/.idea/workspace.xml . I'm also using Yeoman. I hope this answers your question.